# Is a hash function (e.g. SHA) platform independent?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, sha-3, keccak

I need to compare hashed data from different platforms. The hash function used is Keccak's SHA3.

I started with the assumption that the hash generated values were platform independent; but then these two online tools proved me the opposite:

- http://sha3calculator.appspot.com/
- http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html

Here is the respective output when I hashed the word **data** (sha3 256bits):

- 8f54f1c2d0eb5771cd5bf67a6689fcd6eed9444d91a39e5ef32a9b4ae5ca14ff
- efda893aa850b0c0e61f33325615b9d93bcf6b42d60d8f5d37ebc720fd4e3daf

My knowledge on the subject is quite limited, but I have always taken for granted that hash functions were platform independent (that's why we use MD5 checksum, right ?).

Any light on the subject will be highly appreciated.

Best.

Comment: Yes, hash functions should be platform independent. There is probably some encoding problem, different parameters or some implementation bug.

Comment: The final SHA-3 specification hasn't been published yet, so I recommend sticking with SHA-2 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a hash algorithm should return the same value everywhere, aside from encoding issues.

You will get the same hash if you choose the algorithm `Keccak-256` instead, i'm not sure what they use for `SHA3-256`:

http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

Comment: Keccak and SHA3 have differences in padding scheme, so results should be different.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-3, specifically (and distinctly from Keccak) is specified in [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) as of August 2015.

All implementations should product the same results with the same inputs.

Official test Vectors are available at the [NIST CAVP Testing: Secure Hashing](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/secure-hashing.html) page.